# Parallel processing with Numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a >100MB file that needs to be read with `numpy.loadtxt()`

The reading part is the main bottleneck in my code. For a  72MB file it takes `17.3s`

Is is somehow possible to read in a parallel way a file using `loadtxt()`

If possible without splitting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like *numpy.loadtxt()* is your problem.

http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543

http://codrspace.com/durden/performance-lessons-for-reading-ascii-files-into-numpy-arrays/

According to these sites, you're better off not using numpy's load function at all.

**pandas.read_csv** and **read_table** should be helpful from the pandas module.

Comment: I tried `pandas.read_csv()`. It is in fact very fast in comparison with `loadtxt()`.