# Best pandas way to parse table-like data where separation between columns is varying number of whitespaces?

Tags: pandas, text-files

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to read this census-related data (https://www2.census.gov/topics/genealogy/1990surnames/dist.all.last) into a pandas data table directly? So far the only way I can think of to parse the columns is to read each line individually, apply .split() and then use that list to create a data table. This seems like something pandas would have dealt with, but I don't know how.

Comment: `pandas.read_table(url, sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 0):

For single space

```
import pandas as pd pd.read_csv('https://www2.census.gov/topics/genealogy/1990surnames/dist.all.last', sep=' ',header=None)
```

For multiple spaces (here)

```
pd.read_csv('https://www2.census.gov/topics/genealogy/1990surnames/dist.all.last', sep='\s+',header=None)
```

Also see
[Read Space-separated Data with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809061/read-space-separated-data-with-pandas)